# This project references NuGet Packages that are missing:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I've just imported the .sln of the source files of an open source software, and I'm running into many built error like this:

`"This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them."`

```
Right Click this Project> "Manage NuGet Packages" > "Settings":
```

under `"NuGet Package Manager"` drop-down
I do have both options under `"Package Restore"` checked.

How do I enable "NuGet Package Restore" on .csprojs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right-click on your solution, and choose `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...`.

When there are packages used that are not downloaded, you will get a yellow bar with the option to restore packages on top of the `Manage NuGet Packages` screen.

See [this page for more documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog).

You can open the `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution` dialog for a project as well.

You can automate the downloading of packages on build as well, by right-clicking the solution, and choosing `Enable NuGet Package Restore`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue resolved when I updated some packages for which update is available. It might not downloaded those package due to its available update. Updating those packages and clean-build solution worked for me.